# Exponential function 1/x = e

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Why is the following identity true?

$$\lim_{x\to0}(1+\sin2x)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\to0}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+\sin2x)\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

(Explanation is below):

$$\begin{align*}
(1+\sin2x)^{\frac{1}{x}} \quad&{\stackrel{1}{=}}\quad e^{\ln(1+\sin2x)^{\frac{1}{x}}}\\
&{\stackrel{2}{=}}\quad e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+\sin2x)}
\end{align*}$$

Explanation:

1. $a = e^{\ln a} $
2. $\ln a^b = b\ln a$

Comment: ty so much :) saving my life

Answer (score 0):

$$y=(1+\sin(x))^{1/x}$$
$$\ln(y)=\ln\left[(1+\sin x)^{1/x}\right]=\frac1x\ln(1+\sin x)$$
but:
$$y=e^{\ln(y)}=e^{\frac1x\ln(1+\sin x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=1+\sin2x$ and $g(x)=\dfrac1x$. We want to show that $f(x)^{g(x)}=\mathrm{exp}\big(g(x)\cdot\ln f(x)\big)$.

We start by observing that $\exp(ab)=(\exp a)^b$. This follows from the fact that $y^{ab}=\left(y^a\right)^b$.

Therefore:

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{exp}\big(g(x)\cdot\ln f(x)\big)
&=\mathrm{exp}\big(\mathrm{ln}\,f(x)\big)^{g(x)} \\
&=f(x)^{g(x)}
\end{align*}

And we are done.